# C# Display SQL data to HTML Textbox based on Textbox ID

Tags: c#, html, sql

I am creating a web form and I have 5 textbox. The data that will be put here will come from a Stored Proc which returns a table with 3 columns like this:

```
---------------------
|Group| ID  | Amount |
|-----+-----+--------|
|A    |1    | 5      |
|B    |2    | 9      |
|B    |1    | 2      |
|A    |2    | 1      |
|A    |3    | 57     |
----------------------
```

Now, how can I assign, in an efficient way, the specific Amount value to its corresponding textbox which depends on the columns Group and ID like this:

```
txt_A1.Value=5;
txt_A2.Value=1;
txt_A3.Value=5;
txt_B1.Value=2;
txt_B2.Value=9;
```

I am currently using this code but it does not work.

```
string CatID = String.Concat(dr["Group"], dr["ID"]);
var control = Controls.Cast<Control>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == string.Format("txt_{0}", CatID)) as TextBox;
if (control != null)
control.Text = dr["Amount"].ToString();
```

TAKE NOTE that the textbox is an HTML object like `<input type="Text" id="txt_A1" runat="server">`

Comment: Did you try to debug? What error you are getting?.

Comment: @chindiralasampathkumar no error. But no output

Comment: Why don't you use jquery for this purpose? Make an AJAX call, get the data and populate your controls.

Comment: Try adding the runat="server" attribute:

Comment: <input type="Text" id="txt_A1" runat="server" />

Comment: @MAdeelKhalid can you show me how? please

Comment: @OguzOzgul I have put runat="server". I forgot to include it here

Comment: If you have runat="server" then TextBox textBox = FindControl (string.Format("txt_{0}", CatID)) as TextBox; can do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve your task, all those `<input type="text" id="txt_A1">` controls should have `runat="server"` so that server, or code-behind, can access them.

Next, I would suggest using asp.net control `TextBox` instead of `<input>` controls. It's easier to work with them.

Your idea is not bad, but it goes through only first level of controls, meaning that if your input is in `div` (it belongs to that `div`'s controls collection), your code won't find it. You have to make recursive function, to find input controls on page and on all controls that have child controls and all the control's child controls that can have child controls...

So, here's such function. I have made it typed so you can pass type of controls you're searching. In your case, that should be `HtmlInputText` because `input` is generic html text control. In case you're using asp.net `TextBox` controls, you should pass `TextBox` as control type.

```
public IEnumerable<Control> GetControlsOfType<T>(Control parent)
{
    if (parent.HasControls())
    {
        foreach (Control childControl in parent.Controls)
        {
            if (childControl is T)
                yield return childControl;

            foreach (var nextLevel in GetControlsOfType<T>(childControl))
            {
                yield return nextLevel;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

now, use it like this:

```
//find all textControls
var textControls = GetControlsOfType<HtmlInputText>(this);
//find specific control from the list
var control = textControls.FirstOrDefault(t => t.ID == string.Format("txt_{0}", CatID));
//set value
(control as HtmlInputText).Value = "some value";
```

Comment: WOW. you are the best. Thank you for saving me. It works. Thank you